# Как проинкрементировать поле в таблице по юзерам?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Пытаюсь сделать закладки с возможностью менять порядок.
Есть users со связью один ко многим к bookmarks.

Добавил целочисленное поле priority к bookmarks.

Как в миграции проинкрементировать поле в общей куче примерно понимаю:

```
Bookmark.update_all('priority = priority + 1')
```

или

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SET @pri := 0;')
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('UPDATE bookmarks SET priority = ( SELECT @pri := @pri + 1 ) ORDER BY updated_at ASC;')
end
```

Что даст следующее:

bookmarks:

```
user_id: 1, priority:1
user_id: 2, priority:2
user_id: 1, priority:3
user_id: 2, priority:4
```

А как сделать так чтобы поле было проинкрементировано по пользователю?
Т.е. чтобы получить:

bookmarks:

```
user_id: 1, priority:1
user_id: 2, priority:1
user_id: 1, priority:2
user_id: 2, priority:2
```

База большая поэтому ищу решение с максимальным использованием средств бд(Mysql).

**Update** Текущий вариант выглядит так

```
customers = Customer.includes(:bookmarks).where('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookmarks WHERE bookmarks.customer_id = customer_id) > 0').uniq
customers.each do |customer|
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SET @pri := 0;')
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE bookmarks SET priority = ( SELECT @pri := @pri + 1 ) WHERE customer_id = #{customer.id} ORDER BY created_at;")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, получить всех пользователей с их bookmarks:

```
users = User.includes(:bookmarks)
```

И потом для каждого пользователя выполнить инкремент

```
users.each do |user|
  user.bookmarks.update_all('priority = priority + 1')
end
```

Comment: добавил свой текущий вариант